# Setar pino do PIC como entrada e saida com CCS?

Tags: pic

Boa tarde, eu quero alterna um pino do PIC setado como saída para entrada no meio da execução do programa, e em seguida voltar o pino como saída.

Answer (score 1):

usa a diretiva:

```
#use standard_io(A)
```

depois é só usar as funções normais para leitura e escrita: `input (pin)`, `output_high (pin)` e `output_low(pin)`.

Answer (score 1):

Você tem duas opções utilizando diretivas `#USE STANDARD_IO(port)` ou `#USE FAST_IO(port)`:

### #USE STANDARD_IO(port)

**Vantagem:** Ele "cuida" da direção dos pinos. Então quando você utiliza `input(pin)`, `output_high(pin)` ou `output_low(pin)` você não precisa se preocupar com a configuração da direção dos pinos.

**Desvantagem:** Quando você faz uma leitura ou escrita sempre é gerado código a mais para setar a direção do pino, mesmo sem precisar. Desta forma utiliza mais memória e isso pode ser um problema dependendo do tamanho de seu firmware e da memória disponível de seu µControlador.

---

### #USE FAST_IO(port)

**Vantagem:** Utiliza menos memória pois só gera o código necessário para fazer uma leitura ou para escrita no pino.

**Desvantagem:** Você tem que ser cuidadoso e configurar a direção do pino antes de fazer uma leitura ou escrita utilizando o comando `set_tris_x(value)`